# How do I include file in codeIgniter application, which is outside application folder

Tags: codeigniter, include

I want to include this file

```
api/app/PHPexcel/phpexcel.php
```

Into this library

```
application/library/excel.php
```

In codeIgniter. Base url in my config file is empty.

pls help.

Comment: Did you try any thing?

Comment: $file = dirname(FCPATH . '/api/app/PHPexcel/phpexcel.php');....it worked for me.thanks a lot sir

Comment: Don't forget to accept  answer then

Answer (score 0):

On your file try [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

**File-name:** application > library > Excel.php

```
<?php

// dirname will let you access out side application folder.

$file = dirname(FCPATH . '/api/app/PHPexcel/phpexcel.php');

// $file = FCPATH . 'api/app/PHPexcel/phpexcel.php';

require_once $file;

class Excel {

   public function __construct() {

   }

}
```

Folder Layout

- application
- api
- api > app
- system
- index.php

Best not to leave your base_url blank will run into some issues later.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path. Something like:

```
'/var/www/html/api/app/PHPexcel/phpexcel.php'
```

or

```
'C:\wamp\www\api\app\PHPexcel\phpexcel.php'
```

Note that you have some predefined constants in CodeIgniter itself:

```
APPPATH => '/path/to/application/'
FCPATH  => '/path/to/directory/where/index/php/file/is/
etc...
```

Those constants are defined in `index.php` file.
Commonly used practice is to put (e.g.) PHPexcel directory into

```
APPPATH . 'libraries'
```

location so structure could be

```
-application
--libraries
---PHPexcel
----phpexcel.php
---Excel.php # don't forget have it with ucfirst rule if CI3
```

or you can put directory in `third_party` and include it as

```
APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPexcel/phpexcel.php';
```

But it is up to you how do you like to arrange files/directories structure of your app.

Answer (score -1):

In application/config/autoload.php file there is variable named $autoload['libraries'] = array();

you should define your library in this array and your library will be loaded automatically.